# x86 transition from 16bit to 32bit mode

Tags: assembly, x86, microprocessors

I am reading the book "Writing Operating System from Scratch" by Nick Blundell. In one of the chapters, it is explained how we make transition from 16bit mode to 32bit mode. It says that before moving to 32bit mode we should ensure that all the instructions in 16bit mode which are currently inside the pipeline (instruction pipeline inside CPU) are executed. To accomplish this it says, we should make a far jump which causes a pipeline flush which the book says is completing all instructions currently in the different stages of the pipeline.
But what I understood about pipeline flushing is removing all the instructions after the conditional branch from the instruction pipeline due to changed flow of the program.
I am confused between these descriptions, could someone please explain what all happens during pipeline flushing.
Further, the book says a near jump may not be sufficient to do pipeline flushing. I do not understand this as well.

Answer (score 3):

Pipeline flushing is required to empty the pre-fetched and decoded/translated instructions from the pipeline when ever those instructions are not to be executed. This is required both after a conditional jump and after a transition to segment where the instruction set must be decoded with a different logic to the 16-bit real mode. There can be differences in the available opcodes, the segmentation model and the default operand / address size prefix bits (to name a few).

It's possible, that a near jump is optimized in the processor to start prefetching instructions from a certain address immediately after it has been decoded; practically the only difference in near and far jumps is the explicit re-loading of CS (and setting new policies for instruction decoding), which may have been designed to trigger the pipeline flushing.

[1](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html)[Jump instructions in x86][1](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html)

```
if(IsNearJump()) {
    if(IsRelativeJump()) TemporaryEIP = EIP + Destination; //EIP is instruction following JMP instruction;
    else TemporaryEIP == Destination;
    if(!IsWithinCodeSegmentLimits(TemporaryEIP)) Exception(GP(0));
    if(OperandSize == 32) EIP = TemporaryEIP;
    else EIP = TemporaryEIP & 0xFFFF; //OperandSize == 16
    //END
}
if(IsFarJump() && (PE == 0 || (PE == 1 && VM == 1)) { //real-address or virtual-8086 mode
    TemporaryEIP = Destination.Offset; //Destination is ptr16:32 or [m16:32]
    if(!IsWithinCodeSegmentLimits(TemporaryEIP)) Exception(GP(0));
    CS = Destination.SegmentSelector; //Destination ptr16:32 [m16:32]
    if(OperandSize == 32) EIP = TemporaryEIP; //Destination ptr16:32 [m16:32]
    else /*OperandSize == 16*/ EIP = TemporaryEIP & 0xFFFF; //clear upper 16 bits;
    //END
}
```

Comment: Thanks....but if pipeline flushing only removes instructions from the pipeline, why does the book says that it completes all the instructions in the current pipeline.

Comment: Pipeline flushing AFAIK, must mean flushing only the _invalid_ or potentially invalid instructions from the pipeline. But there are also valid instructions in the pipeline, which are meant to be completed. One method, which is purely speculation, is that a far call places a sentinel to the pipeline, which in essence completes all instructions up to the far call, marks all other instructions invalid and starts to fill the pipeline with micro-code associated with the far-call.